# How to get ContentBlockModel/Component Model from PageModel directly using asp.net core rendering sdk

Tags: jss, layout-service

I am following the document https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html to create a test sample project for Sitecore Headless Development.

Everything is working perfectly and I got an understanding of how the PageModel is automatically bound with the requested page.

```
public IActionResult Index(PageModel page)
```

And how the component model is being registered.

```
.AddModelBoundView<ContentBlockModel>("ContentBlock")
```

And how it is being used in views.

```
@model ContentBlockModel
```

but I have some different requirements. I want to get ContentBlockModel directly from the page route something like

```
ContentBlockModel contenBlockModel = page.Route.Placeholders["myproject-main"][0]
```

Is there any way to get ContentBlockModel from PageModel directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get a [`Component`](https://doc.sitecore.com/resources/sitecore-asp-dot-net-rendering-sdk/100/api/Sitecore.LayoutService.Client.Response.Model.Component.html) from the `Placeholder`, you can use the [`ReadFields<T>()` method](https://doc.sitecore.com/resources/sitecore-asp-dot-net-rendering-sdk/100/api/Sitecore.LayoutService.Client.Response.Model.FieldsReader.html#Sitecore_LayoutService_Client_Response_Model_FieldsReader_ReadFields__1) or other `Read` methods to get strongly-typed values from it. Keep in mind that this is just JSON deserialization, the ASP.NET model binding attributes won't work here.